# Audio streaming using rtmp protocol in videogular

Tags: html, audio-streaming, rtmp, meanjs, videogular

I am using videogular player for playing audio .

```
test.push({
          src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("myserver/mypath/to/song.mp3"),
          type: "audio/mp3"
        });
```

This is working fine. But i need to stream `rtmp protocol url` instead of `"myserver/mypath/to/song.mp3"`. 
I came across several players like video.js,jwplayer. But i want to stream in videogular only.
But i dont knw how to achieve that. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can't use rtmp with Videogular because it doesn't have Flash support. You can try to write your own Flash plugin or try to use this one, but it looks pretty old tho, so I don't know if it would work: https://github.com/NamPNQ/bower-videogular-flash